# Is frame animation the right way for gaming

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am making a game (similar to other strategy games like Clash). I am using the sprite animation (frame animation) to animate buildings. However my resources is causing my APK to easily go over 100M and I am not even done with half of the animations.

How do games manage to keep their size well under 100M? Is frame/sprite animation not the way to go?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using .jpg? You can save a lot of space with compression without lose a lot of quality.

Comment: I am thinking about that. I am using PNG. But with JPG, you lose all the transparency as the building will need to be on a map so you want transparent background of the building, right?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll lost transparency.

Comment: Can you use other texture formats: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/01/efficient-game-textures-with-hardware.html